# Call an async function periodically?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following function to call `s(c)` every 24 hours.

```
def schedule_next_sync():
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = t.replace(hour=0) + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    def wrapper():
        s(c)
        schedule_next_sync()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(datetime.datetime.timestamp(t), wrapper)
```

However, `s()` will be changed to an async function.

```
async def s(c):
```

How to update `schedule_next_sync` for async function? Should run `s()` synchronously? Or change `schedule_next_sync()` to an async function?

Comment: Is there a need of async here ? if we have to call a function periodically then why should i make it asynchronous ? curious to know the use case

Comment: What's wrong with a simple while loop for if you just want to call ~ every 1 s?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi, `s()` will need to call some async functions.

Comment: @2e0byo, I actually need to schedule it at night everyday. Updated the question.

Comment: Have you considered the function `loop.call_at(timestamp, callback, *args)`?  In your case, `callback` could be `asyncio.create_task` and the only argument would be `s(c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Once `s` is async, you could use `asyncio.sleep()` instead of the lower-level `add_timeout()`:

```
async def schedule_next_sync():
    async def call_forever():
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await s(c)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().create_task(call_forever())
```

If you really want to do it with timeouts, something like this should work:

```
def schedule_next_sync():
    t = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
    def wrapper():
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(s(c))
        task.add_done_callback(lambda _: schedule_next_sync())
    loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    loop.add_timeout(datetime.datetime.timestamp(t), wrapper)
```

Comment: Actually I will need to schedule the call at a particular time every day so I will need to use the second one. I'm using Python 3.6 so there is no `get_running_loop()`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 Ah, the example in the question was misleading then. You could still use `asyncio.sleep()` and just calculate the time to sleep until the next event. (To me the sleep version is much more natural.) In Python 3.6 you can just use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` instead of `get_running_loop()`, it should return the same thing when called from inside a coroutine or callback. The only difference is that `get_running_loop()` raises an exception when _not_ called from a coroutine or callback, i.e. it effectively asserts that it's called from an async context.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question. I actually need to make it run every night. I changed to one second for debugging.